# VB.net multithreading to fix a device driver

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, synchronization, device-driver, retransmit-timeout

I have tried to code a VB.net based device driver for receiving data in an ASTM protocol.
The driver has to further process the data and send it to a database -based software ("biologic"). Indeed, I succeeded in accomplishing both tasks when a small set of data is being received. But when receiving a huge amount of data there is a problem. The software which sends the data to my driver does not get the ACK command and re-transmissions of frames occur. I am not so familiar with multi-threading, but have recently heard it might solve my problem, as it is related with synchronization and timeouts.. Please find below the current version of my code. I would very appreciate if you could advise and assist me with how to modify it to add threads and synchronize them in a way that the driver would insert new data into a queue and send an ACK command, but will do it in parallel with sending the data from the queue to the database. It, I guess, should do it in a synchronized way... Please Help...

```
Imports System.Threading
Module MainModule
Const SAMPLE As String = "H|\^&|||BLA||||||||V1.0|20141030110328" & vbCrLf & _
                            "P|1" & vbCrLf & _
                            "O|1|2280||^^^PLUSANF^449353738032|R||20141030110156|||||||20141030110156" & vbCrLf & _
                            "R|1|^^^GND^449353738032|INST_ONGOING|||||P|||20141030110156|20141030111213|BACTECFX^93^5^2^D-C09" & vbCrLf & _
                            "L|1|N"
Const LOG_FILE As String = "\\srvfs1\general\groups\biologic\BD\log.txt"
Const STX As String = Chr(2)
Const ETX As String = Chr(3)
Const EOT As String = Chr(4)
Const ENQ As String = Chr(5)
Const NAK As String = Chr(25)
Const ETB As String = Chr(23)
Const ACKNOWLEDGE_MESSAGE As String = Chr(&H0) + Chr(&H6)

Private WithEvents _RS232 As Rs232

Dim messageDateTime, accessionNumber, testId, testSequence, collectedDateTime, receivedDateTime, resultFields() As String
Dim resultTypeCode, vialNumber, testStatus, preliminaryFinalStatus, entryDateTime, classificationDateTime As String
Dim instrumentFields(), instrumentType, mediaType, protocol, instrumentNumber, station As String
Dim classificationId As Integer
Dim resultReceived, orderReceived As Boolean
Dim frameNumber As String

Sub Main()
    'updateBiologicDatabase("449381999474", "B-K08", "1480", 2, "20140603032419", "20140617090442", 93, 5, "7171")
    'Dim test As Integer = getClassificationId("INST_NEGATIVE")
    'If 1 = 1 Then
    '    closeConnections()
    '    Return
    'End If
    _RS232 = New Rs232()
    Try
        '// Setup parameters
        With _RS232
            .BaudRate = 9600
            .DataBit = 8
            .StopBit = Rs232.DataStopBit.StopBit_1
            '.Parity = Rs232.DataParity.Parity_Even
            .Parity = Rs232.DataParity.Parity_None
            '.Timeout = Int32.Parse(txtTimeout.Text)
            .Timeout = 20000
            .UseXonXoff = False

        End With
        '// Initializes port
        _RS232.Open()
        '// Set state of RTS / DTS
        '_RS232.Dtr = (chkDTR.CheckState = CheckState.Checked)
        '_RS232.Rts = (chkRTS.CheckState = CheckState.Checked)
        _RS232.Dtr = True
        _RS232.Rts = True
        If Not _RS232.IsOpen Then
            UpdateLog("Port not opened")
        End If
        Console.WriteLine("Before read port")
        'Console.ReadLine()
        ReadFromPort()
        'Button1_Click_1(Nothing, Nothing)
    Catch Ex As Exception
        UpdateLog(Ex.Message)
    End Try
    'closeConnections()
End Sub
Sub ReadFromPort()
    '----------------------
    Dim buffer As String = ""
    Dim nextChar, checkSum, crlf As String
    '// Clear Tx/Rx Buffers
    _RS232.PurgeBuffer(Rs232.PurgeBuffers.TxClear Or Rs232.PurgeBuffers.RXClear)
    _RS232.Write(ACKNOWLEDGE_MESSAGE)
    UpdateLog("Before loop")
    Do While True
        Try
            _RS232.Read(1)
            nextChar = _RS232.InputStreamString
            Select Case nextChar
                Case STX
                    UpdateLog("STX received")
                    _RS232.Read(1)
                    nextChar = _RS232.InputStreamString
                    frameNumber = nextChar
                Case ETX
                    UpdateLog("ETX received")
                    _RS232.Read(2)
                    checkSum = _RS232.InputStreamString()
                    _RS232.Read(2)
                    crlf = _RS232.InputStreamString()
                    HandleBuffer(buffer)
                    buffer = ""
                    _RS232.Write(ACKNOWLEDGE_MESSAGE + frameNumber)
                    UpdateLog("Sent: <ACK>" + frameNumber)
                    'Thread.Sleep(500)
                    '_RS232.Write(ACKNOWLEDGE_MESSAGE)
                    'Thread.Sleep(500)
                    '_RS232.Write(ACKNOWLEDGE_MESSAGE)
                Case ETB
                    UpdateLog("ETB received")
                    _RS232.Read(2)
                    checkSum = _RS232.InputStreamString()
                    'UpdateLog("Checksum after ETB = " & checkSum)
                    _RS232.Read(2)
                    crlf = _RS232.InputStreamString()
                    _RS232.Write(ACKNOWLEDGE_MESSAGE + frameNumber)
                    UpdateLog("Sent: <ACK>" + frameNumber)
                    'Thread.Sleep(500)
                    '_RS232.Write(ACKNOWLEDGE_MESSAGE)
                    'Thread.Sleep(500)
                    '_RS232.Write(ACKNOWLEDGE_MESSAGE)
                Case EOT
                    UpdateLog("EOT received")
                    HandleBuffer(buffer)
                    buffer = ""
                    _RS232.Write(ACKNOWLEDGE_MESSAGE + frameNumber)
                    UpdateLog("Sent: <ACK>" + frameNumber)
                    'Thread.Sleep(500)
                    '_RS232.Write(ACKNOWLEDGE_MESSAGE)
                    'Thread.Sleep(500)
                    '_RS232.Write(ACKNOWLEDGE_MESSAGE)
                Case ENQ
                    UpdateLog("ENQ received")
                    _RS232.Write(ACKNOWLEDGE_MESSAGE + frameNumber)
                    UpdateLog("Sent: " + ACKNOWLEDGE_MESSAGE + frameNumber)
                    'Thread.Sleep(500)
                    '_RS232.Write(ACKNOWLEDGE_MESSAGE)
                    'Thread.Sleep(500)
                    '_RS232.Write(ACKNOWLEDGE_MESSAGE)
                Case Else
                    'If Asc(nextChar) = 13 Then
                    '    _RS232.Read(1)
                    '    nextChar = _RS232.InputStreamString
                    '    If Asc(nextChar) = 10 Then
                    '        buffer += vbCrLf
                    '        UpdateLog("CRLF after line")
                    '    Else
                    '        UpdateLog("0A did not appear after 0D")
                    '    End If
                    'Else
                    'UpdateLog("Regular Character: " & nextChar & " - " & Asc(nextChar))
                    buffer += nextChar
                    'End If
            End Select
        Catch Ex As Exception
            If String.IsNullOrEmpty(buffer) Then
                Continue Do
            End If
            Console.WriteLine("Timeout")
            Continue Do
        End Try
    Loop
End Sub
''' <summary>
''' Handle the buffer received from RS232
''' </summary>
''' <param name="aBuffer"></param>
''' <remarks></remarks>
Sub HandleBuffer(aBuffer As String)
    ' From BD
    'H|\^&|||BLA||||||||V1.00|19981019184200
    'Q|1|^Acc123|||R
    'L|1|N
    ' Acknowledge
    'H|\^&||||||||||||19981019184200
    'P|1||PatId123||Doe^John^R^Jr.^Dr.||19651029|M||2 Main St.^Baltimore^ MD^21211^USA||(410) 316 - 4000|JSMITH||||||P\AM\AMX||||19981015120000||324|||||||ER|St. Josephs Hospital()
    'O|1|Acc123^ ^ ^Seq123|| ^ ^ ^MGIT_960_GND|||19981019023300|||SJB^MMF|A|||19981019045200|Blood^Arm|MJones|410)555–1234^410)555–9876^(410)555–7777|||||19981020053400|62||O||Nos
    'L|1|F
    ' Result
    'H|\^&|||BLA|||||||| V1.00 |19981019184200
    'P|1||PatId123
    'O|1|Acc123||^^^MGIT_960_GND^430100065178
    'R|1|^^^GND^430100065178|INST_POSITIVE^87|||||P|||19981019153400|19981020145000|MGIT960^^42^3^B/A12
    'L|1|F

    'Dim acknowledge As String
    Dim lines() As String
    Dim patientid As String = ""
    Dim patientName As String = ""
    Dim gender As String = ""
    Dim birthDate As DateTime = "1900-01-01"
    messageDateTime = ""

    Try
        ' Divide the buffer to different lines
        lines = aBuffer.Split(vbCrLf)
        If lines.Count < 2 Then
            Exit Sub
        End If
        For Each line In lines
            HandleLine(line)
        Next
        ' Update the Biologic database only when the 'R' (Result) line was received or the 'O' (Order) line was received
        If resultReceived Or orderReceived Then
            If String.IsNullOrEmpty(classificationDateTime) Then
                classificationDateTime = entryDateTime
            End If
            updateBiologicDatabase(vialNumber, station, accessionNumber, classificationId, classificationDateTime, entryDateTime, mediaType, protocol, instrumentNumber)
            resultReceived = False
            orderReceived = False
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        UpdateLog(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
''' <summary>
''' Habdle each line separately
''' </summary>
''' <param name="aLine"></param>
''' <remarks></remarks>
Sub HandleLine(aLine As String)
    Const HEADER_PREFIX As String = "H"
    'Const PATIENT_PREFIX As String = "P"
    Const ORDER_PREFIX As String = "O"
    Const RESULT_PREFIX As String = "R"
    Const MESSAGE_DATE_TIME_POSITION As Integer = 13
    Const ACCESSION_NUMBER_POSITION As Integer = 2
    Const TEST_POSITION As Integer = 4
    Const TEST_ID_POSITION As Integer = 3
    Const TEST_SEQUENCE_POSITION As Integer = 4
    Const COLLECTED_DATE_TIME_POSITION As Integer = 7
    Const RECEIVED_DATE_TIME_POSITION As Integer = 14
    Const RESULT_POSITION As Integer = 2
    Const RESULT_TYPE_CODE_POSITION As Integer = 3
    Const RESULT_TYPE_SEQUENCE_POSITION As Integer = 4
    Const TEST_STATUS_POSITION As Integer = 3
    Const PRELIMINARY_FINAL_STATUS_POSITION As Integer = 8
    Const TEST_START_DATE_TIME_POSITION As Integer = 11
    Const RESULT_STATUS_DATE_TIME_POSITION As Integer = 12
    Const INSTRUMENT_POSITION As Integer = 13
    Const INSTRUMENT_TYPE_POSITION = 0
    Const MEDIA_TYPE_POSITION = 1
    Const PROTOCOL_POSITION = 2
    Const INSTRUMENT_NUMBER_POSITION = 3
    Const INSTRUMENT_LOCATION_POSITION = 4
    Dim fields(), tests() As String
    Dim pos As Integer

    Try
        If String.IsNullOrEmpty(aLine) Then
            Return
        End If
        If aLine.Length < 10 Then
            Return
        End If
        fields = aLine.Split("|")
        If Asc(fields(0)) = Asc(vbLf) Then
            fields(0) = fields(0).Substring(1, 1)
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        UpdateLog(ex.Message)
        Return
    End Try
    Try
        Select Case fields(0)
            Case HEADER_PREFIX
                UpdateLog(aLine)
                If aLine.Length > 10 Then
                    messageDateTime = fields(MESSAGE_DATE_TIME_POSITION)
                    orderReceived = False
                    resultReceived = False
                    'UpdateLog("Message Date Time: " & messageDateTime)
                End If
            Case ORDER_PREFIX
                UpdateLog(aLine)
                accessionNumber = fields(ACCESSION_NUMBER_POSITION)
                tests = fields(TEST_POSITION).Split("^")
                testId = tests(TEST_ID_POSITION)
                'UpdateLog("Test Id: " & testId)
                vialNumber = tests(TEST_SEQUENCE_POSITION)
                'UpdateLog("Test Sequence: " & testSequence)
                collectedDateTime = fields(COLLECTED_DATE_TIME_POSITION)
                'UpdateLog("Collected Date Time: " & collectedDateTime)
                receivedDateTime = fields(RECEIVED_DATE_TIME_POSITION)
                orderReceived = True
            Case RESULT_PREFIX
                UpdateLog(aLine)
                resultFields = fields(RESULT_POSITION).Split("^")
                resultTypeCode = resultFields(RESULT_TYPE_CODE_POSITION)
                vialNumber = resultFields(RESULT_TYPE_SEQUENCE_POSITION)
                'UpdateLog("Result Test Sequence: " & vialNumber)
                testStatus = fields(TEST_STATUS_POSITION)
                'UpdateLog("Test Status / Classification: " & testStatus)
                classificationId = getClassificationId(testStatus)
                If classificationId < 1 Then
                    UpdateLog("Unknown Classification: " & testStatus)
                    Return
                End If
                preliminaryFinalStatus = fields(PRELIMINARY_FINAL_STATUS_POSITION)
                entryDateTime = fields(TEST_START_DATE_TIME_POSITION)
                classificationDateTime = fields(RESULT_STATUS_DATE_TIME_POSITION)
                pos = classificationDateTime.IndexOf("\")
                If pos > 0 Then
                    classificationDateTime = classificationDateTime.Substring(0, pos)
                End If
                'R|1|^^^GND^449238953154|INST_REMOVED|||||P|||20141102164617|20141127125123|BACTECFX^92^5^2
                instrumentFields = fields(INSTRUMENT_POSITION).Split("^")
                instrumentType = instrumentFields(INSTRUMENT_TYPE_POSITION)
                mediaType = instrumentFields(MEDIA_TYPE_POSITION)
                protocol = instrumentFields(PROTOCOL_POSITION)
                instrumentNumber = instrumentFields(INSTRUMENT_NUMBER_POSITION)
                If instrumentFields.Length > 4 Then
                    station = instrumentFields(INSTRUMENT_LOCATION_POSITION)
                Else
                    station = ""
                End If

                resultReceived = True
                'UpdateLog("result Received: ")

        End Select

    Catch ex As Exception
        UpdateLog(ex.Message)
    End Try

End Sub
Sub UpdateLog(ByVal aMessage As String)
    Try
        Console.WriteLine(aMessage)
        My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText(LOG_FILE, Format(Now(), "dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss") & ": " & aMessage & vbCrLf, True)
    Catch ex As Exception
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
Sub Dispose()
    _RS232.Close()
End Sub
```

End Module

Comment: Just bumped into this, working on a similar project. I know this is an old post, still for help on the topic - I don't believe you would require multithreading. Simply create a large string array and store all the frames you received there, instead of calling HandleBuffer with unpredictable delays due to database access. I cannot image that the amount of frames&data for these 9600 baud protocols is so large that it cannot be easily kept in a string array. Then, after closing the serial connection, loop through the string array and update your database.

Answer (score 0):

Old post, I know, but just in case anyone runs into it: I wouldn't suggest multithreading to solve this problem.

Create a VB string array and store all the frames you received there, instead of calling HandleBuffer(...) with unpredictable delays due to database access.

I cannot image that the amount of frames and data for these 9600 baud protocols is so large that it cannot be easily kept in a VB.NET string array.

Then, after closing the serial connection, loop through the string array and update your database.